# passing a symbolic matrix to sympy.lambdify

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I want to create a function of a symbolic matrix in sympy and then lambdify it for evaluation in numpy. Let's try the simple function that returns exactly what I feed it f(x) = x, but eventually Id like to do something like take the trace of the matrix, or something fancier.

It's fine when x is a sympy.Symbol:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import Matrix, MatrixSymbol

x = sy.Symbol('x')
f = sy.lambdify(x, x, 'numpy')
f(Matrix((3,))) # returns Matrix([[3]])
```

But not when x is a sympy.MatrixSymbol:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import Matrix, MatrixSymbol

x = sy.MatrixSymbol('x', 2, 2)
f = sy.lambdify(x, x, 'numpy')
f(Matrix((3,))) # should return Matrix((3,)), right?
```

It tells me:

```
lambda() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Thanks for any ideas or guidance!

Comment: I'd say this is a bug. You can open an issue at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new.

Comment: autowrap may already support what you desire. Here is a test showing the trace: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/e8d101572c2a4632427ee7daf937a70b4a124404/sympy/external/tests/test_autowrap.py#L59

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cludge hack.  mySymbol takes a string (keep it short), and n and m are the desired matrix dimensions.

```
def makeMatrix(mySymbol,n,m):       #makes a lambdafiable matrix

    myMatrix = zeros(n,m)

    for i in numpy.arange(n):
        for j in numpy.arange(m):
            myStr = mySymbol+"_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)

            myMatrix[i,j]=sympify(myStr)

    return myMatrix
```